# Как записать инфу через код PHP в базу MySQL без дубликатов?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, циклы, запись

*Я недавно начал учить PHP, а с MySQL вообще плохо знаком.
Сейчас я пишу код, выполняя задачу поставленную самому себе в целях самообучения.
И сейчас появилась проблемка в коде - нужно сделать наиболее оптимально сверку значений либо что-то другое, что бы дубликаты не записывались.
Привожу код в текстовом виде и скриншотом, для удобного чтения.*

---

P.S: Читал про INSERT IGNORE но как-то не понятна его логика, объясните понятно пожалуйста. Или предложите вариант лучше.
Когда я запустил код с if - (логика) - проверка по ссылке в базе (т.к. ссылка то уникальна и если ее в базе нету, значит можно записывать) код залил в базу 700+ записей (на дубликаты не проверял), а по идеи он должен был залить только 10 (т.к. на одной странице только 10 статей).

---

[image: question]

---

Сам кусочек кода:

```
/*запись данных в базу*/
$link_test=mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT * FROM `php_dns`.`habra_post`");
if(!$link_test){
  $bd-> query("INSERT IGNORE INTO habra_post SET title='$title1', text_body='$text1', reg_date='$date1', 
    full_text='$full_text', next_date='$date_nextd', link='$html_in'");
      if($bd==false)
      {
          // echo "<br>Oll OK";
      // }
      // else
      // {
         echo mysqli_error();
      }
}}}
```

Comment: Если в поле таблицы недопустимы повторения, этому полю можно присвоить параметр `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Как вариант - сделать поле в БД со свойством UNIQUE. (см. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038040/mysql-make-an-existing-field-unique)

Comment: про unique читал, что он крайне нежелателен в качестве решения этой задачи.

Comment: Крайне нежелателен? Если означенные данные уникальны в вашей области unique constraint **необходим**, дабы избежать нарушений целостности при параллельных изменениях.

Answer (score 1):

INSERT IGNORE актуален только в том случае если у тебя есть уникальный или первичный ключ в таблице если же его (их) нет то это выражение бессмысленно. В данном случае тебе необходимо вначале проверить существование записи в таблице, а потом произвести запись.
То-есть вначале проверить существование записи

```
SELECT * FROM `php_dns`.`habra_post` WHERE title='$title1' AND text_body='$text1' AND reg_date='$date1' AND full_text='$full_text' AND next_date='$date_nextd' AND link='$html_in'
```

Если запись найдена то игнорируй ее если нет то создай новую.

Но вот эта запись слишком не оптимальна.

```
SELECT * FROM `php_dns`.`habra_post` WHERE title='$title1' AND text_body='$text1' AND reg_date='$date1' AND full_text='$full_text' AND next_date='$date_nextd' AND link='$html_in'
```

Тебе необходимо определить какие именно записи не должны дублироваться и только их проверять, а лучше сразу создать уникальные ключи. Если этого делать не хочешь то оптимизируй или правильно организуй таблицу - например `full_text` если он слишком громоздкий то создай ещё одну колонку с `md5` `full_text` и сравнивай их, а лучше вообще его перенести в другую таблицу. Или вот у тебя есть `link` - если это ссылка на страницу то для каждого поста она уникальна - можешь только её проверять - то-есть если она есть то и запись есть.